# How can I prove ~(X - 1) == -X in Two's complement?

Tags: bit-manipulation

We know in order to get the lowest set bit of a number we do `X &= -X` . That is in fact a condensed form of `X &= ~(X - 1)` . What I don't get here is how `~(X - 1) == -X` ?

I can get to the answer using a truth table easily but I'm looking for a Boolean Algebra type of proof.

Comment: Is X already masked ?

Comment: Write down the bits on a piece of paper. For `X`, for `-X`, for `X - 1`, and for `~(X - 1)`.

Comment: That doesn't get the LSB, it gets the lowest set bit. The LSB would be `X & 1`.

Comment: What do you allow as starting assumptions? There are various proofs starting with the *other* definition of negation, definitions of subtractions, a particular implementation of addition, and the fact that "all bits set"+1 = 0. But it has to start somewhere, there is no purely algebraic reason for that particular definition of negation (if there was, then negation would only exist for bitvectors - it's nice that it exists for other objects too)